# Simplified version of Ray Tracing to find the nearest object extending out from a vector

Tags: algorithm

I have a 2D array consisting of 0s and 1s. I have a vector originating from a 0 to any direction and I need to find the nearest 1 that intersects with the vector in that direction and its distance

So I've looked into ray tracing, but most materials on the subject seemed rather unintuitive and mostly talked about how to do refraction and color calculations.

Is there something simpler than the said algorithm?

Thanks.

Comment: What about brute force - start at the origin of the vector, and iterate through the elements of the array along your chosen line until you find a 1?

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do... Essentially bresenham' line algorithm should help me do this atm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adapt the [Bresenham' line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) to this task.